# Saving Repeated Iterations to Database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, sum

I'm pretty new to rails.

I have multiple datapoints that I am saving in my database for a subject called "quarterback". All of those datapoints are added together to for the value "xoi_qb". This calculation is performed in my model:

```
  def xoi_qb
    sum=0
    sum+= passing_yards|| 0
    sum+= passing_yards|| 0
    sum+= qb_rushing|| 0
```

Each value will change over time, and so the total of the sum, "xoi_qb", will change over time. Currently, the total for "xoi_qb" just updates and the previous total is lost.

What I'd like to do is save each iteration of that total, every time it's changed. I don't want to do a "cron job", because I don't want to create a time-based schedule that performs a rake to see if any changes were made...I just want that total for each "quarterback" value "xoi_qb" to be saved to the database ***each time*** that I make a change.

That way, each "quarterback" will end up with many "xoi_qb" values that go up and down in value. Right now, I just want to solve this and then eventually I'd like to plot the datapoints in a chart (with Highcharts or something similar). But for now, I just need to know how to save each "xoi_qb" total with each change.

I have no idea how to do this.

Comment: you might need to create a separate table in you database to track `xoi_qb` values when ever it is updated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `before_save` callback in your corresponding model followed by accessing previous value as `_was`

Is should look something like:

```
before_save :store_last_xoi_qb

def store_last_xoi_qb
  last_xoi_qb = self.xoi_qb_was
  # do your things
end
```

Comment: But how do I define "xoi_qb_was"? I'm getting the error 

`undefined method `xoi_qb_was'`

Comment: Its a Rails feature. `_was` appended to an attribute returns its previous value.

Comment: Ok...why do you think I'm getting the "undefined method error?" It looks like "last_xoi_qb" would need to be defined as well, no? (And thank you so much for your help!!! I must be close) Could it be because of this in the controller?...

  `@quarterback = QbPlayer.find(params[:id])
    # Update the object
    if  @quarterback.update_attributes(quarterback_params)
      # If update succeeds, redirect to the index action
      flash[:notice] = "Player updated successfully."
      redirect_to(:action => 'show', :id => @quarterback.id)`

Comment: Oh because you need to `include ActiveModel::Dirty`. [Here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Dirty.html)

Comment: Include ActiveModel::Dirty in the Controller, correct?